# Create multiple folders in upload media folder

Tags: uploads, media, seo

Is there a way to upload images to multiple folders in the media library without using a plugin. This is to create file paths to enhance SEO for an online store. I would like to have the URL show category folder names instead of longer hyphenated filenames. At the moment I can only create 1 path to upload to.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to WPSE. Unfortunately no, that is not possible.

Depending on your [Media settings](https://wordpress.org/support/article/settings-media-screen/) files uploaded to the Media Library either go directly to the Uploads directory or are organized into month- and year-based subdirectories within Uploads.

You'll need to find and use some existing plugin, or create one of your own, to achieve other structure.